# Communication between extension and plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, npapi, browser-plugin

I have written a Firefox extension which queries some browser information. I need to send this information to an NPAPI plugin from my extension.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to communicate between NPAPI plugins and the extension's JavaScript code? I am grateful for any useful links or code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin provides a [scripting interface](http://colonelpanic.net/2009/08/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-three/), the extension can just call its functions when wants to send the information.

You need to have access to the plugin element, e.g.:

- `var plug = someDocument.getElementById('yourPluginId');`
- or by finding the `embed`/`object` elements you want without a specific ID

To find the elements without having a specific `id`, you could e.g. collect them [using XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) or by using [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
Keep in mind that the mime type might not necessarily identify your plugin if you are not using one specific to your plugin. You might need to check custom plugin name/version information in addition to the `type` attribute.

Once you have the plugin element you can simply call functions on it from JavaScript (e.g. `plug.someFunction(someData);`).

Comment: i mean to say how firefox extension can call the scriptable npapi function ?

Comment: how to find embed/object elements without specific id ?

Comment: Actually the plugin is written by us only and we dont know how to specify the pluginId for the plugin...

Comment: @user1530767, are you injecting the plugin from the addon, does it get used on your website, ...? I.e. can you set the id attribute for the object or embed element?

Comment: No, this plugin been registered for Mozilla browser and for a perticular MIME type of any website its getting loaded !